# What is the purpose of this weird duck?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I noticed (only today) whenever I visit any SE website, I get this weird comic on bottom of page:

[image]

For a short while, I was wondering if my browser has been comprised by some web malware, so I decided to run it in a virtual machine: nothing happens.

Is this some sort of a funny thing SE developers did or has it actually any usefulness?

Comment: It's an april-fools joke [Stack Exchange has been taken over by a rubber duck!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck)

Comment: Oh ...xDDDDDDD :) thank you very much for the link.... I started to get worried :) @t3chb0t

Comment: It's Apple's beta of the new improved Siri.

Comment: For the record, I had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's serious. It's about [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).
The majority of questions asked on Stack Exchange can be solved using a rubber duck, without ever posting a question, potentially saving a large number of users from embarrassment.
This new experimental feature is called Quack Overflow.
The experiment will end on April 1 + 1 day, depending on your timezone.

Enjoy while it lasts!

Comment: So useful, that I keep one on my desk (mine's called Bob, for obvious reasons).  Sometimes I'll explain my code to Bob; more often I'll redirect colleagues who are rubberducking at me...